# How to display a node edit form in custom URL

Tags: 8, nodes

I have a node created (using [Default content](https://www.drupal.org/project/default_content)) as part of the site install and it is available to edit at `node/[nid]/edit`. However, this node holds some of the site-specific content (for example, content to display on sitewide banner) and should be available under the site configuration section instead of `node/[nid]/edit` so that I can restrict the edit access with specific permission.

Why not the configuration/settings form? Because the node type has rich fields like image upload, entity reference, etc, and would be nice to use the node/entity's field API and display modes.

Is there a way to get the edit page of **just** this node at `/admin/config/system/banner-settings`?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new menu item in a custom module

```yaml
# mymodule.routing.yml

mymodule.banner_settings_form:
  path: /admin/config/system/banner-settings/{node}
  defaults:
    _entity_form: node.edit
    # Copy UUID from exported default content.
    node: 05d6a9e5-6e78-42bb-b3fe-b9a6344f4022
  requirements:
    _entity_access: node.update
    # Custom permission check.
    _permission: 'administer site banner configuration'
  options:
    _admin_route: true
    _node_operation_route: true
    parameters:
      node:
        type: 'entity:node'
        # Part of jsonapi module.
        converter: paramconverter.jsonapi.entity_uuid
```

Visiting `/admin/config/system/banner-settings` would take the default UUID value from the route and renders the form.

P.S: After saving the form it would redirect back to `node/[nid]` and this can be avoided by passing `?destination=<your path>` in the link.